# What a granny is supposed to say to respond to "Thank You"?

Tags: spoken-english, colloquial-language, responses

A [post](https://www.idioms.online/english-idioms-8-ways-to-respond-to-thank-you/) gives "8 Ways to Respond to Thank You". I didn't find one is appropriate the following situation.

Imagine that, a granny prepares a breakfast for her grandson.

> Grandson: thank you, granny.
>
> Granny: That's OK.

which sounds weird, right?

So, what a granny is supposed to say to respond to "Thank You"?

Comment: "You are welcome!" or something specific to the scenario like, "I hope you like it."

Comment: 'That's OK' doesn't sound 'weird' at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loving relative would probably respond differently from a stranger to being thanked. A person in a business or formal situation might say one of a number of things, such as 'you are welcome', 'that's OK', 'don't mention it', etc (I don't like it when people say 'no problem'). However, there is no 'rule' governing what a fond grandmother has to say to a polite and grateful child. She might pat the child on the head and say some affectionate thing - 'that's OK my little chickadee, eat it up', for example.

Answer (score -1):

"You're welcome" or "It's nothing".